# Using of RaiseCanExecuteChanged

Tags: delegatecommand

I make two methodes like this:

private void Next(string argument)
{
    Current = Clients[Clients.IndexOf(Current) + 1];
      ((DelegateCommand)NextCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}

private void Previous(string argument)
{
   Current = Clients[Clients.IndexOf(Current) - 1];
    ((DelegateCommand)PreviousCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

}

and bind to the xaml:

Every thing work fine. And the next button becomes inactive/grey out when it hits the last post.
The problem is it (the Next button) still inactive when I click the Previous button. The Next button becomes inactive all the time. 
My question is how I could make the Next button active again? Thank for all help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a WPF Application.

There are several reasons your button could become / stay inactive:

- Your CanExecute implementation is faulty and returns false even if it should return true
- You didnt implement CanExecute or didnt hook it up correctly
- The CommandManager didn't realize it's time to requery the commands
- You've got a problem with the Focus on your Window / Control

You need to show more of the code so it gives us a broader picture of what you are trying to do.